# Is power outage dangerous in BIOS?

Tags: laptop, bios, power-supply

I recently had problems with my adapter for my laptop, and I think there is a problem with the connector. But to know that, I have no other solution but to test if my computer is powered or not. Since I don't want my HDD to be damaged if there is a power outage, and since I don't have a battery anymore, can I safely launch the BIOS interface and test the adapter even if there might be brutal shutdowns ?

Comment: I would be more worried about the filesystem and all the other parts.  The loss of electricity isn't good for software or hardware.

Comment: The hard disk still starts up even if you just enter the BIOS. The file systems won't be mounted yet so there's no risk of file corruption however hard disks don't like brutal power losses, so that could lead to catastrophic drive failure and loss of all of your data (but the data itself won't be corrupt so it'll be recoverable assuming you can pay a data recovery company).